# Testing Android project with jar dependecies

Tags: android, testing

My Android project has a few jar libraries as dependencies. Alone, it compiles and works well.
I wrote a little test project but running it I don't get any result (no tests passed or failed) nor any error, but in the logcat's output there are warnings like this:

```
06-06 14:55:43.533: INFO/dalvikvm(7049): Failed resolving Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/InMobiAdapter; interface 315 'Lcom/inmobi/androidsdk/InMobiAdDelegate;'
06-06 14:55:43.533: WARN/dalvikvm(7049): Link of class 'Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/InMobiAdapter;' failed
06-06 14:55:43.533: INFO/dalvikvm(7049): Failed resolving Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/InMobiAdapter; interface 407 'Lcom/inmobi/androidsdk/InMobiAdDelegate;'
06-06 14:55:43.533: WARN/dalvikvm(7049): Link of class 'Lcom/adwhirl/adapters/InMobiAdapter;' failed
06-06 14:55:43.553: DEBUG/dalvikvm(7049): GC_CONCURRENT freed 471K, 51% free 2880K/5831K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+4ms
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049): Cannot load class. Make sure it is in your apk. Class name: 'com.adwhirl.adapters.InMobiAdapter'. Message: com.adwhirl.adapters.InMobiAdapter
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adwhirl.adapters.InMobiAdapter
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.createPackageInfo(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:89)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.access$000(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:40)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource$1.load(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:51)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource$1.load(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:48)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.SimpleCache.get(SimpleCache.java:31)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.getPackageInfo(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:73)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.getSubpackages(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:48)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.addTopLevelClassesTo(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:61)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.getTopLevelClassesRecursive(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:55)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.testCaseClassesInPackage(TestGrouping.java:154)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.addPackagesRecursive(TestGrouping.java:115)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.includePackages(TestSuiteBuilder.java:103)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:360)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3398)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:977)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.adwhirl.adapters.InMobiAdapter
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     ... 26 more
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adwhirl.adapters.InMobiAdapter in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/com.mypackage.test-1.apk:/data/app/com.mypackage-2.apk]
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-06 14:55:43.553: WARN/ClassPathPackageInfoSource(7049):     ... 26 more
```

As you can see seems that there are problem exporting the libraries, infact I get an error like that for every library.
I read [in this blog post](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-testing-external-libraries.html) that to get it to work, it should be enough to export all the libraries in the main project, but for me didn't works. Any other idea?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?  I tried the suggested solutions / blog as well but still did not have success.

Comment: The suggested solution isn't working for me neither. In case it matters, my missing library depends on a native library (that load flawlessly in my main project)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to your project that uses .jar files (i.e. project under test). Click right button -> Properties-> Java Build Path -> Order and Export -> check libraries there

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem using Maven. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me was - in 'Order and Import' section bringing my jar file up

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put the jars in libs intead than lib ?

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17