# ADT20 and External JAR

Tags: java, android, jar, adt

[image]I have tried absolutely everything to avoid the NoClassDefFoundError when trying to use an external jar. No dice.  WTF ADT?!

From a clean, brand new project, add external jar to build path, put in `libs` folder, make sure it's checked.  Android -> Fix Project Properties, adding and removing, rinsing and repeating.  I checked the contents of the jar, and my files are there!  I referenced it 20 ways, removed added and rebuilt, still the dern thing can't be found!!

Is there a way someone has, from step 1, made an external jar work inside Android using eclipse and ADT 20?

**Edit 1**

I tried adding it into only the `libs/` folder, and tried what Ali suggested [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059152/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-adt-17-known-issue).  I think I'm going to have to just try and add the source to my project directly, but that seems plain silly.

Comment: Have you tried not putting it in Libraries, but only in libs?

Comment: Try **either** add external jar to build path, **or** put in libs folder, do not use both at the same time.

Comment: Starting from scratch, trying both of those, still no dice.  I recreated the jar, thinking there was something there too, but no. Nada. Brand new fancy clean Android project, even went as far as adding the `android-support-v4` jar which works. I can see all my classes in the **Android Dependencies** directory and all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh.  My.  Goodness.

Turns out, **Android (still) does NOT support Java 7** and when I created my external project, it had the 1.7 (Java 7) as the default compliance level!  Switching that down to match my Android project's compliance makes it all dandy.

Stuff like

```
List<MyClass> mList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And various `@Override` apparently made Android stick it's nose in the air.

Hopefully this helps someone else out who's been going bald over this issue!