# libGDX won't run on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i've done everything according to this tutorial: http://steigert.blogspot.cz/2012/02/1-libgdx-tutorial-introduction.html. Everything compiles fine but after start android app crashes. Here's log cat output:

```
10-23 18:33:34.128: E/dalvikvm(386): Could not find class 'cz.pohy.tyrian.Tyrian', referenced from method cz.pohy.tyrian_android_tut.MainActivity.onCreate
10-23 18:33:34.128: W/dalvikvm(386): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1100 (Lcz/pohy/tyrian/Tyrian;) in Lcz/pohy/tyrian_android_tut/MainActivity;
10-23 18:33:34.128: D/dalvikvm(386): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0004
10-23 18:33:34.168: D/dalvikvm(386): VFY: dead code 0x0006-000c in Lcz/pohy/tyrian_android_tut/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
10-23 18:33:34.188: D/dalvikvm(386): Trying to load lib /data/data/cz.pohy.tyrian_android_tut/lib/libgdx.so 0x40514fa8
10-23 18:33:34.208: D/dalvikvm(386): Added shared lib /data/data/cz.pohy.tyrian_android_tut/lib/libgdx.so 0x40514fa8
10-23 18:33:34.208: D/dalvikvm(386): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/cz.pohy.tyrian_android_tut/lib/libgdx.so 0x40514fa8, skipping init
10-23 18:33:34.248: D/AndroidRuntime(386): Shutting down VM
10-23 18:33:34.248: W/dalvikvm(386): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cz.pohy.tyrian.Tyrian
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at cz.pohy.tyrian_android_tut.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-23 18:33:34.268: E/AndroidRuntime(386):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 18:33:40.878: I/Process(386): Sending signal. PID: 386 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the step 10 of the same tutorial, he mentions a ClassNotFoundException bug with ADT plugin version 17. There are instructions to solve the problem:

http://steigert.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/10-libgdx-tutorial-accelerator-and.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Anyway, this wasn't the only issue (or the issue at all). I had to also change Compiler Compliance Level in Project->Properties->Java Builder to 1.6. In both, android and desktop project.

Comment: I'm not sure about the desktop project, but Android does have problems with java 1.7, as pointed by the docs on libgdx [http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup)